# sum certain values between when the first and last observation equals a certain value

Tags: r

I have something like:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1,1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),         
               have=c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,0,0,1, 1,0,0),
               wantsum=c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0))
```

I want to sum the number of 0's per group, but only when the first and last observation is equal to 1. Something like:

```
#   group have wantsum
#1      1    1       2
#2      1    0       2
#3      1    1       2
#4      1    0       2
#5      1    1       2
#6      2    1       3
#7      2    0       3
#8      2    0       3
#9      2    0       3
#10     2    1       3
#11     3    1       0
#12     3    0       0
#13     3    0       0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a condition after grouping by 'group', by checking `if` `all` the `first` and `last` observation in 'have' are 1, then get the `sum` of '0' values or `else` return 0

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(wantsum2 = if(all(c(first(have), last(have)) == 1)) sum(have == 0) else 0)
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
#   group  have wantsum wantsum2
#   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1     1       2        2
# 2     1     0       2        2
# 3     1     1       2        2
# 4     1     0       2        2
# 5     1     1       2        2
# 6     2     1       3        3
# 7     2     0       3        3
# 8     2     0       3        3
# 9     2     0       3        3
#10     2     1       3        3
#11     3     1       0        0
#12     3     0       0        0
#13     3     0       0        0
```

---

There are many ways to make this happen, so the `if/else` condition can be modified by multiplying the logical vector generated from `all` and  as `TRUE/FALSE` -> `1/0`, any number multiplied by 0 -> 0 and multiplied by 1 -> number

```
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(wantsum2 = sum(have == 0) * all(c(first(have), last(have)) == 1) )
```